# Web application security in J2EE7

Tags: wildfly-8, seam2, picketlink

I'm migrating a seam 2.2 application to the Java EE 7 platform.

I'm looking for an alternative for the *@Restrict* annotations.

I'm using Wildfly 8.2 as an application platform and I found some references from seam3 to the PicketLink project and annotations like *@LoggedIn* and *@RolesAllowed*.

However I don't find these annotations in the packaged version of picketlink. Can anyone point me in the direction on how to get these working in a CDI environment? e.g. maven dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

My maven dependency was on *picketlink-api* and not *picketlink*.